# Unity - random looping idle

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

Here is a basic setup of locomotion.

[image: Animation locomotion]

It works this way it is connected, I have walk and run animation, and stand as idle, I added 3 new stand("Idle") animations, and cant figure a way to make them random pick after walk is finished, and loop till next destination is given.
I tried adding new substate machine, but still cant figure a way to connect it the proper way.

Here is the image of current setup, this way when agent stops, it returns to idle state, and animation loops till new destination is given.
I want the same behavior but when he returns to idle, I want it to randomly loop with 3 new states

Comment: You should check this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html

Comment: blend tree is no use here, i dont need to blend more animations.

Comment: Yeah, but you can blend for random int. And set this random int from code.

Comment: great thanks, it works, i created new blend tree and reconnect it with same parameters as previous idle, and it works.

Comment: Ok, I'll write answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`BlendTree`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html) for that.

Just set Random `float` using `Random` class and use BlendTree to blend animations using that tree.

Comment: BlendTree wont accept int as parameter, it only uses float so i can use that